# Problems with selection jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, selector

In my code, I have this loop, which brings up various 2-hour time blocks.  I am finding it very difficult to get the text out of .clientSearchSectionButtonHiddenTextEndTime.  I am having no problems getting the text out of .clientSearchSectionButtonHiddenTextStartTime.

PHP

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

            $startTimeVar = $row["startTime"];
            $startTimeCorrected = date("g:i a", strtotime($startTimeVar));
            $endTimeVar = $row["endTime"];
            $endTimeCorrected = date("g:i a", strtotime($endTimeVar));

                echo
                '<div class = "clientSearchSectionButtonText">
                    <div class = "clientSearchSectionButtonTextTime">
                        '.$startTimeCorrected.' - '.$endTimeCorrected.'
                    </div>
                </div>
                <span  class = "clientSearchSectionButtonHiddenTextStartTime" style = "display: none;">
                    '.$row["startTime"].'
                </span>
                <span  class = "clientSearchSectionButtonHiddenTextEndTime" style = "display: none;">
                    '.$row["endTime"].'
                </span>
            <div class = "buttonBreak">
            </div>';
        }
```

JQuery - I have tried to select it in many ways.  $this gives the div clientSearchSectionButtonTextTime.  I have tried lots of different things including .parent().next, parent().sibling, .sibling...etc

```
/*----SELECT TIME----*/ 
$(".clientSearchSectionButtonTextTime").live("click", function() {
    startTime = $(this).parent().next(".clientSearchSectionButtonHiddenTextStartTime").text();
    endTime = $(this).parent().next(".clientSearchSectionButtonHiddenTextEndTime").text();
    alert (endTime);
});
```

Comment: Extremely long class names, consider shortening them! ** Have you debugged it?** Please an alert in the click event!

Comment: yeah, it's a super intricate design with everything from the whole site on one page...without long class names the information goes to the wrong spot...i don't normally use them, but in this case it was the only way

Comment: im just frustrated I can't grab that text...i've also tried to use the startTime and add 2 hours, but that brings up its own problems when I try that.  Plus, i'd like the freedom to make the time blocks more tan 3 hours if I want.

Comment: I have debugged it for hours, jsfiddle says everything looks fine, and I have added other alerts that do work.  alert(startTime) works, which is most important

Comment: What about `alert(endTime);`?

Comment: alert(endTime) is not working, but that's what I've been trying to get to work the whole time.  alert(endTime) is already in the code above...Thanks for looking into this with me!

Comment: Move it above the `startTime` definition and see if it fires. If not then it is a problem with the `live(...`. If so, then look into the `next(...` part

Comment: it fires correctly for start time using alert(startTime)

Comment: I am going to post an answer so I can post proper code and lead you through the debug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure enough, `.next()` only selects **the immediately next** sibling. If a selector is given, that single sibling is tested to match it, otherwise result is empty.

Try `.nextAll('.uncannyClassName')` and you should be good to go.

```
/*----SELECT TIME----*/ 
$(".clientSearchSectionButtonTextTime").live("click", function() {
    startTime = $(this).parent().nextAll(".clientSearchSectionButtonHiddenTextStartTime").text();
    endTime = $(this).parent().nextAll(".clientSearchSectionButtonHiddenTextEndTime").text();
    alert (endTime);
});
```

I'd also add it to the `.clientSearchSectionButtonHiddenTextStartTime` too, to allow future scalability to the DOM (and not just by selecting the next whichever element).

Comment: In addition to this. If you are working with HTML5 (which I strongly recommend), you could use the `data-my-data-chunk` attributes to store "hidden" data into any element and retrieve them using `$(this).data('my-data-chunk')`.

Comment: My bet is on this one, this is what I would have answered

Comment: YES! This worked, and thank you so much for explaining it to me.  I'm sure everyone will find it helpful

Answer (score 1):

if you don't need to see you can use a input hidden like this

```
<input type="hidden" name="clientSearchSectionButtonHiddenTextStartTime[]" value="<?php echo $row['startTime']; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="clientSearchSectionButtonHiddenTextEndTime[]" value="<?php echo $row['endTime']; ?>" />
```

But returning to your trouble you can do a thing like this in your html, just for chiarify

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  $startTimeVar = $row["startTime"];
  $startTimeCorrected = date("g:i a", strtotime($startTimeVar));
  $endTimeVar = $row["endTime"];
  $endTimeCorrected = date("g:i a", strtotime($endTimeVar));
  echo '<div class="group">
    <div class="clientSearchSectionButtonText">
      <div class="clientSearchSectionButtonTextTime">'.$startTimeCorrected.' - '.$endTimeCorrected.'</div>
    </div>
    <span class="clientSearchSectionButtonHiddenTextStartTime" style="display: none;">'.$row["startTime"].'</span>
    <span class="clientSearchSectionButtonHiddenTextEndTime" style="display: none;">'.$row["endTime"].'</span>
     <div class="buttonBreak"></div>
   </div>';
}
```

Group every record, so you can simply use jquery like this

```
/*----SELECT TIME----*/ 
$(".clientSearchSectionButtonTextTime").live("click", function() {
   startTime = $(this).parent('groups').find(".clientSearchSectionButtonHiddenTextStartTime").text();
   endTime = $(this).parent('groups').find(".clientSearchSectionButtonHiddenTextEndTime").text();
   alert (endTime);
```

});

I didn't try it, but should be ok

Comment: So I may start rearranging things to match your first suggestion in a minute, but the second suggestions still returns a blank alert.  It's weird, all of the solutions everyone has come up with should work, including my original ones...we must be looking in the wrong spot?  Exploring in Firebug, the data is definitely there in the box.

Comment: or if you want to be more specific you can numerate any record giving an id, so you can simply get your desired value simply get the id an example could be like this: `<div class="group">` becomes `<div id="group<?php $count; ?>` and in jquery you can take easily using an element selction like this `$('#group' + id + '.clientSearchSectionButtonHiddenTextStartTime')`

Comment: The first part of this post became very helpful later on, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try using .find() instead of .next()

For exmaple:

```
endTime = $(this).parent().find(".clientSearchSectionButtonHiddenTextEndTime").text();
```

Comment: I'm getting a blank alert, same as .next()

Comment: when I explore in firebug, the text is definitely there

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '
    <div name="'.$count.'" class = "clientSearchSectionButtonText">
        <div class = "clientSearchSectionButtonTextTime">
            '.$startTimeCorrected.' - '.$endTimeCorrected.'
        </div>
    </div>
    <span  name="'.$count.'" class = "clientSearchSectionButtonHiddenTextStartTime" style = "display: none;">
                '.$row["startTime"].'
    </span>
    <span  name="'.$count.'" class = "clientSearchSectionButtonHiddenTextEndTime" style = "display: none;">
                '.$row["endTime"].'
    </span>
    <div class = "buttonBreak">
    </div>';

$(".clientSearchSectionButtonTextTime").live("click", function() {

    name = $(this).getAttribute("name"); 
    startTime = $('.clientSearchSectionButtonHiddenTextStartTime[name="'+name+'"]');

});
```

It's been awhile since I wrote my own CSS selectors, but you should be able to get the idea.
Putting a common identifier on each of your div/spans, makes it easier than trying to navigate through the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

If the `next()` and `closest()` solutions do not work, you need to debug your code. Start by executing this and see if it works:

```
/*----SELECT TIME----*/ 
$(".clientSearchSectionButtonTextTime").live("click", function() {
    alert ($(this).parent().next(".clientSearchSectionButtonHiddenTextStartTime").text());
    //startTime = $(this).parent().next(".clientSearchSectionButtonHiddenTextStartTime").text();
    //endTime = $(this).parent().next(".clientSearchSectionButtonHiddenTextEndTime").text();
});
```